# Track mouse activity in unfocused TideSDK app

Tags: tidesdk

I would like to know if it is possible to track mousemovement in a TideSDK application even when the application is not focused/active.

I am currently using:

```
   $(window).on("mousemove",function(e){
       console.log(new Date().getTime());
   });
```

But that obviously doesn't track anything when an other application is active.

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify which operating system (win/linux/osx) you are referring to in the context of above request.

AFRIK the feature needs to be supported by underlying operating system. Generally operating system only send event to the application window if they are in focus.. so we would not be getting event passed to our process hence cannot track the mouse movement without focus.

If you know any way to do the same, do let me know .. I will try to accommodate the same feature in TideSDK. If you have suggestion regarding any particular technology to use, please file a feature request at: https://github.com/TideSDK/TideSDK/issues

Thanks